# regexp_like to find 10 occurrences of 0's

Tags: sql, oracle

```
with smpl as
(
    select '000-000-0000' num from dual union
    select '0000000000' from dual union
    select '00000000000' from dual
)
select * from smpl
where regexp_like(num, '0{10}');
```

Output:

```
0000000000
00000000000
```

How to get records with 10 occurences 0's with optional '-'
Expected:

```
0000000000
000-000-0000
```

Comment: Are there other characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to point out that you can do this strictly with regular expressions.  If you are looking for the pattern anywhere in the string:

```
where regexp_like(num, '(\-*0){10}')
```

If you are looking for only that pattern in the string:

```
where regexp_like(num, '^(\-*0){10}\-*$')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `TRANSLATE` to strip out the unwanted characters and then `LENGTH`

```sql
with smpl as
(
    select '000-000-0000' num from dual union
    select '0000000000' from dual union
    select '000000000' from dual union
    select '00000000000' from dual
)
select * from smpl
where LENGTH( TRANSLATE( num, '0-', '0' ) ) = 10
```

or compare to `0000000000`:

```sql
with smpl as
(
    select '000-000-0000' num from dual union
    select '0000000000' from dual union
    select '000000000' from dual union
    select '00000000000' from dual
)
select * from smpl
where TRANSLATE( num, '0-', '0' ) = '0000000000'
```

**Outputs**:

> ```
> | NUM          |
> | :----------- |
> | 000-000-0000 |
> | 0000000000   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3f6955c5b0fba1240cb6e7164aee38bf)*

Answer (score 0):

With regexp, this is an easy way:

```
where regexp_count(num, '0') = 10
```

However, if the only character different from `'0'` is a `'-'`, I would prefer the non-regexp solution